# Is there a function that returns index where RegEx match starts?

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings of 15 characters long. I am performing some pattern matching on it with a regular expression. I want to know the position of the substring where the `IsMatch()` function returns true.

**Question:** Is there is any function that returns the index of the match?

Comment: Do you mean the index of a match _in_ the string or the index _of_ a matching string in a collection?

Comment: index of match in the string...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

For multiple matches you can use code similar to this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex("as");
foreach (Match match in rx.Matches("as as as as"))
{
    int i = match.Index;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Use Match instead of IsMatch:

```
    Match match = Regex.Match("abcde", "c");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int index = match.Index;
        Console.WriteLine("Index of match: " + index);
    }
```

Output:

```
Index of match: 2
```

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using IsMatch, use the [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) method. This will return a [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx), which contains a number of [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) objects. These have a property [Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

```
Regex.Match("abcd", "c").Index

2
```

Note# Should check the result of Match.Success, because its return 0, and can confuse with Position 0, Please refer to Mark Byers Answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this returns 0 if the regex does not match, which is probably not what you want. You should check match.Success first (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use `IsMatch()`, use `Matches`:

```
        const string stringToTest = "abcedfghijklghmnopqghrstuvwxyz";
        const string patternToMatch = "gh*";

        Regex regex = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);

        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToTest); 

        foreach (Match match in matches )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Console.Writeline("Random String".IndexOf("om"));
```

This will output a 4

a -1 indicates no match

Comment: Question asks about "pattern matching with a regular expression".  `IndexOf` doesn't support patterns, only simple strings.