# Find all occurrences of a pattern whether they overlap or not

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this snippet in my method:

```
MatchCollection words = Regex.Matches("dog cat fun toy", @"\w\w\w.\w?");
foreach (Match match in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

I expected to see something like this:

> dog c
>   cat f
>   fun t

But program came up with just that:

> dog c
>   fun t

As I understood, it skipped second occurrence because part of it was in previous occurrence. But I still want to see it. How should I correct my snippet?

Comment: Have you tried look-aheads?

Comment: Search one-by-one and start over after beginning of previous match... See more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851795/is-there-a-function-that-returns-index-where-regex-match-starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try some thing like that

```
var regX = new Regex(@"\w\w\w.\w?");
string pattern = "dog cat fun toy";

int i = 0;
while (i < pattern.Length)
{
    var m = regX.Match(pattern, i);
    if (!m.Success) break;

    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    i = m.Index + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not a universal solution, but pertinent to you case, the following snippet can do the job:

```
string _input = "dog cat fun toy";
string[] _arr = _input.Split(' ');
string _out = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < _arr.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (_arr[i].Length == 3) { _out+=_arr[i]+" "+_arr[i+1].Substring(0,1)+";";}
}
```

where string _`out` contains all matches separated by "`;`" (or any other char). Alternatively, you can send the output to Console:

```
string _input = "dog cat fun toy";
string[] _arr = _input.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < _arr.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (_arr[i].Length == 3) {Console.WriteLine(_arr[i]+" "+_arr[i+1].Substring(0,1));}
}
```

Hope this may help.