# Substring search in string using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am looking in a string for operators. I need the actual operator and its index in the string

For example: `x>10&y>=10`

Operators

```
>
&
>=
=
```

So I need results like

```
>  1
&  4
>= 6
```

So I wrote the code like this

```
string substr= "x>10&y>=10";
List<string> substringList = new List<string>{">", "&", ">=", "="};

 var orderedOccurances = substringList
      .Where((substr) => str.IndexOf(substr, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
      .Select((substr, inx) => new 
          { substr, inx = str.IndexOf(substr, StringComparison.Ordinal) })
      .OrderBy(x => x.inx).ToList();
```

However I got results like this(obviously)

```
 > 1
 & 4
 > 6
 = 7
```

I can use a for loop for the search and cover this error scenario. But I like the linq short hand code. Is there anyway that I can cover the error condition using lambdas/linq?

Comment: Where is this monstreous LINQ-statement shorter and in particular better readable than a simple foreach-loop?

Comment: I sort of agree to that point. I still would like to know if linq can be done for this scenario.

Comment: Don't do any of this. You need a lexer, so write a lexer.

Comment: this is the sort of thing regular expressions handle best, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851795/is-there-a-function-that-returns-index-where-regex-match-starts

Comment: @David sure, now add support for parenthesis. Still convinced regular expresisons are best?

Comment: More specifically: write a lexer that yields a sequence of tokens, where tokens know their position and text. You can then use LINQ to query the sequence of tokens.

Comment: @Eric, will try now

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/  This seems quite relevant.

Comment: Does this seem a little Code Review-y to anyone else? Posting the working code would be useful for translation purposes.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth except it doesn't work....

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Fair enough, I got the impression there was a solution in the background and we were being asked to translate it.

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you want is to scan your sequence for the characters '<', '>', '=' and '&', and if any of them found remember the index and the found character, if '<' or '>' is found you want to know if '=' is after it, and if so, the next search should start after the '='.

Note that you didn't specify what you want with `&=` or `==`.

Whenever you have to scan strings for some syntax, it is always wise to at least consider the use of regular expressions.

According to the specification above you want a regular expression that matches if you find any of the following:

- '<='
- '>='
- '='
- '&'
- '<' followed by something else than '='
- '>' followed by something else than '='

Code would be simple:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string expression = ...;
var regex = new RegularExpression("&|<=|>=|[<>][^=]");
var matches = regex.Matches(expression);
```

Object `matches` is an array of `Match` objects. Every `match` object has properties `Index`, `Length` and `Value`; exactly the properties you want.

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Match {match.Value} found"
        + " at index {match.Index} with length {match.Length}");
}
```

The vertical bar `|` in the regular expression means an OR; the `[ ]` means *any of the characters between the brackets*,; the `[^ ]` means *NOT any of the characters between the brackets*.

So a match is found if either `&` or `<=` or `>=` or any character in `<>` which is not followed by `=`.

If you also want to find &= and ==, then your reguilar expression would be even easier:

- find any <>&= that is followed by =
- or find any <>&= that is not followed by =

Code:

```
var regex = new Regex("[<>&=]|[<>&=][^=]");
```

A good online regex tester where you can check your regular expression [can be found here](https://regex101.com/). This shows also which matches are found and a description of the syntax of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more general alternative:

```
string str = "x>10&y>=10";

var result = Regex.Matches(str, @">=|>|&|=").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new { s = m.Value, i = m.Index }).ToList();
```

Result:

```
>   1
&   4
>=  6
```

or a bit shorter if there aren't any other operators in the string:

```
var d = Regex.Matches(str, @"\W+").Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(m => m.Index, m => m.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are bent on using LINQ you could do the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int Index, string Substring)> GetAllIndicees(this string str, IEnumerable<string> subtrings)
{
    IEnumerable<(int Index, string Substring)> GetAllIndicees(string substring)
    {
        if (substring.Length > str.Length)
            return Enumerable.Empty<(int, string)>();

        if (substring.Length == str.Length)
            return Enumerable.Repeat((0, str), 1);

        return from start in Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length - substring.Length + 1)
               where str.Substring(start, substring.Length).Equals(substring)
               select (start, substring);
    }

    var alloperators = subtrings.SelectMany(s => GetAllIndicees(s));
    return alloperators.Where(o => !alloperators.Except(new[] { o })
                                                .Any(other => o.Index >= other.Index &&
                                                              o.Index < other.Index + other.Substring.Length &&
                                                              other.Substring.Contains(o.Substring)));    
}
```

*using c#7 syntax here becuase code is more concise and readable but its easily translatable to previous versions.*

And now if you do:

```
var substr = "x>10&y>=10";
var operators = new HashSet<string>(new[] { ">", "&", ">=", "=" });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filteredOperators.Select(o => $"[{o.Operator}: {o.Index}]")));
```

You'll get the expected result:

```
[>: 1], [&: 4], [>=: 6]
```

Is this "better" than using other tools? I'm not so sure.